# How "the sleep" changes a phrase? Where it is appropriate to use the definite article?

Tags: grammar, difference, articles

There is a computer game called "Silence of the sleep" and I wonder, why "the sleep"? How would you understand it without the article (and do you understand it now?)

In addition
I was searching in the dictionary and found that when the sleep refers to a period of sleeping, it is used as a singular countable noun:

> I had a little sleep in the afternoon.
>    She was woken from a deep
>   sleep by a ring at the door.

But I simply cannot tell the difference between the mass noun sleep:

> I didn’t get much sleep last night.
>    Her eyes were red through lack
>   of sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a game title (*Silence of the Sleep*), not something used in a regular sentence.

From [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/321870/Silence_of_the_Sleep/) (emphasis mine):

> You play as a man called Jacob Reeves. A man who has lost his reason to live. He throws himself into **a blackness** to end his misery, but instead of it being the end he wakes up without a memory of his life before.

Barring further research into the game itself, I'm going to assume that this period of *blackness* is being referred to as *the Sleep* in the game title.

So, not only is *sleep* being used as a countable noun here, but the game title refers to a *specific* instance of sleep—one the main character wakes up from with amnesia. As such, it uses the definite article.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. Would you be so kind and look into the other part of my question?

Comment: @user970696 I don't understand the second part of your question beyond what you've already provided examples of. When it's a mass noun, it refers to the general condition; when it's a countable noun, it refers to one or more events.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the name is "Silence of the Sleep", with a capital S in Sleep. I haven't found a full description of the game but Sleep may be a group of people, a dragon, another world or whatever. It's a proper noun.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, I think that this is the meaning used in your context.

[**the**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/the)

> used to say that the particular person or thing being mentioned is the
>   best, most famous, etc. In this use, "the" is usually given strong
>   pronunciation:
>
> *Harry's Bar is the place to go. 
> You don't mean you met **the Will Smith**
>   (= the film star), do you?*